# Does GCC 7.3 contain all c++17 features?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, c++17, gcc7

I'm trying to build CMake project that use c++17 dialect with the CMake command:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
)
```

I see that it set the compiler flag "-std=c++1z", but I still getting errors that indicate for not sufficient c++ dialect:

error: ‘reduce’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘to_chars_result’ was not declared in this scope

which is suppose to come from  and  from c++ 17

This project does compile when I'm build it with windows

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017 seems to say that support for "Elementary string conversions", which I guess includes `to_chars_result`, was only completed in version 11.1.

Answer (score 4):

> Does GCC 7.3 contain all c++17 features?

No. The compiler has all language features according to documentation, but the standard library is missing a few things.

Comment: How can I know if the features I need is available from the version I'm using?

Comment: @NadavSagie [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) is the place I go to first for these types of questions.

Comment: @NadavSagie If the documentation of the language implementation says that it's done in the version that you use, then you can know that it's available. There are also feature test macros.